# Heter for shaving during the week of Tisha B'Av for work reasons

Tags: halacha, nine-days, tisha-bav, shaving

Is there any posek who allows shaving during shavua shechal bo (the week in which Tisha B'Av falls, up to Tisha B'Av itself) if, by not shaving, one may lose his job?
R' Moshe Feinstein allows shaving up to shavua shechal bo if required by the job, but not during shavua shechal bo.
Does anyone allow during that period too?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for the timely question! Note, though, that this site makes no guarantee of validity, and does not offer professional (particularly rabbinic) advice: treat information from this site like it came from a crowd of your friends. Also, please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account for [access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557) to more features, and [changing](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/edit/2945) your username (unless you're attached to the number 2945).

Comment: Will you accept answers which permit shaving during that time even without the job complication?

Comment: Do you have a source for this ruling of Rav Moshe?

Comment: @Loewian see https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/87093/11501

Comment: I have not found such a heter. For further reference, see https://halachablog.com/2016/07/28/shaving-and-haircuts-during-the-three-weeks/comment-page-1/ and https://ph.yhb.org.il/en/05-08-11/