# Shave during sefirah for a business meeting?

Tags: halacha, sefirat-ha-omer, employment, shaving

Jews generally do not shave during the period of Sefirah (from Pesach to Shavuot) since this period is a period of mourning.

If someone is meeting with a new propective client, what are the conditions that would allow him to shave his beard to look more presentable and make a better first impression, and perhaps assist in closing the deal?

Comment: It stands to reason that switching ones practice from the first to the second half or vice versa is preferable than relying on shas hadchak

Answer (score 1):

As you write Jews generally do not shave. This being said, I know of two approaches to *kulot* relevant to your question. R Yehuda Balsam conveniently writes them up [here](http://bknworg.weebly.com/uploads/5/9/9/5/5995719/shaving_during_sefira.pdf)

> **In a situation when one has a situation in which he will lose money,
>   or possibly his job**, R Moshe Feinstein writes (O.C. 4:102) that it is
>   permissible to shave. However, during the week in which Tish’a b’av
>   falls out, since it is halachikly assur m’drabanan to shave, one may
>   not do so under these circumstances.

dinonline expands on this

> As R Moshe Feinstein explains elsewhere (Choshen Mishpat 1:93), **this leniency
>   only applies if an actual loss would be incurred**. If appearing
>   unshaven merely causes ridicule or embarrassment, the leniency does
>   not apply. Clearly, this will also be true of the discomfort a person
>   suffers from not shaving for a number of days.
>
> A similar ruling was given by R Shlomo Zalman Auerbach (Maadanei
>   Shlomo) concerning the Omer period: **It is permitted to shave for one’s
>   livelihood, but it is otherwise forbidden**.
>
> [However], “Kuntress Liknos Chochmah” cites R Yosef Shalom Elyashiv
>   that today it is forbidden to shave during the Omer even for purposes
>   of one’s livelihood, since being unshaven today does not cause a
>   person to look odd. This clearly depends on a person’s environment and
>   in practice if a person’s livelihood might be at stake the consensus
>   is to be lenient.

The second approach is from R Yosef Ber Soloveitchik (again from [here](http://bknworg.weebly.com/uploads/5/9/9/5/5995719/shaving_during_sefira.pdf))

> In Nefesh Harav p. 191 he writes that shaving was permissible
>   during sefirah. He reasons that when the bnei yisrael accept a new
>   minhag, that minhag must be patterned after an existing halacha,
>   either mid’oraisah or mid’rabanan. An aveil observes three major steps
>   in his mourning: 1) the ‘shivah’ period, observed during the first
>   week, 2) the ‘shloshim’ which is the remaining thirty days, 3) the
>   remaining twelve months. Rav Soloveitchik assumed that the aveilus of
>   sefirah was patterned after the aveilus of the twelve months. During
>   this period, both shaving and haircuts are prohibited. However, the
>   gemarah (mo’ed kattan 22b) writes that if he becomes disheveled ‘ad
>   sheyig’ar bo chaveirav’-until his friends scold him, he may cut his
>   hair and shave.
>
> **Thus, one who normally shaves every day,  and refrains from doing so
>   for a few days would be considered to have reached this point. Thus,
>   it is permissible for him to shave during this period** (it is important
>   to note that Rav Soloveitchik himself did not trim his beard during
>   sefirah, because he did not consider that to be sufficiently unkempt
>   to apply this din.) R Soloveitchik’s opinion is obviously not the
>   mainstream shittah, but it has been accepted by some of his Talmidim.