# Ashkenazi leniencies before shavua shechal bo

Tags: halacha, minhag, ashkenazi, nine-days, leniencies

Ashkenazim extend the Talmudic prohibitions of *shavua shechal bo tisha b'av* (the week of the 9th of Av) to the beginning of the month. Are there Ashkenazi leniencies from Rosh Chodesh Av until *shavua shechal bo* that reflect the fact that the prohibitions during these days are not from the *gemara*?

Comment: I don't have time to look up sources right now, which is why I'm not posting this as an answer, but there are a number of _t'shuvos_ that discuss whether something, normally avoided during the nine days, can be done out of necessity and say "you can do it until _shavua shechal bo tish'a b'Av_". So the answer to your question is "yes".

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29667/759

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 122:5](http://www.yonanewman.org/kizzur/kizzur122.html#5), cutting nails is only forbidden during *shavua shechal bo*.

> קציצת הצפרנים אין לאסור רק בשבוע שחל בו תשעה באב...
>
> Cutting the fingernails should not be prohibited except in the week of the 9th of Av.

(I wouldn't have known this if @Danny Schoemann hadn't posted it to his [Halacho a Day blog](http://halocho.blogspot.co.il/2015/07/halocho-1617-cutting-nails-during-3.html) a couple weeks ago.)